# Falta tradução de "Pergunta Protegida"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Hoje me deparei com a seguinte pergunta: [Problema ao usar 'Google Fonts'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5729/problema-ao-usar-google-fonts), onde reparei que não está traduzido o texto de "questão protegida" quando bot sinaliza a pergunta:

[image: Captura de Tela]

---

#### Onde se lê:

> "This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site."

#### Sugiro que se traduza para:

> "Esta pergunta está protegida para prevenir textos do tipo "obrigado!", "Eu também!", ou respostas (do tipo spam) de novos usuários. Para respondê-la, você deve ter [reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) mínima de 10 pontos neste site."

Comment: psss... Passa a tua sugestão para uma resposta, assim os utilizadores podem votar a favor ou contra. Mais tarde tens também a oportunidade de marcar a mesma como "Correta" e fechar este tópico quando a tradução estiver aplicada.

Comment: Esse bug ainda existe até hoje. :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode ser por ser português de Portugal, mas eu iria com algo deste género:

> Esta pergunta está protegida para evitar respostas do tipo "obrigado!", "Eu também!", ou spam de novos utilizadores. Para responder, deverá ter uma reputação mínima de 10 pontos neste site.

Comment: Se trocar "utilizadores" por usuários, e a segunda frase por "É preciso ter uma reputação mínima de 10 pontos neste site para responder", seria aceitável para os portugueses?

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa à versão do Zuul, que não soaria estranha aos brasileiros (e aos portugueses?):

> Esta pergunta está protegida para evitar respostas do tipo "obrigado!", "Eu também!", ou spam de novos usuários. É preciso ter uma reputação mínima de 10 pontos neste site para responder.

Answer (score 1):

Corrigido para:

> Esta pergunta está protegida para evitar respostas do tipo "obrigado!", "Eu também!", ou spam de novos usuários. É necessário que você tenha pelo menos $rep$ pontos de reputação para respondê-la.

É uma mescla das respostas que vi aqui

Answer (score 0):

Com orientação do @Zuul coloco aqui a minha sugestão.

Sugiro traduzir para:

> Esta pergunta está protegida para prevenir textos do tipo "obrigado!", "Eu também!", ou respostas (do tipo spam) de novos usuários. Para respondê-la, você deve ter reputação mínima de 10 pontos neste site.