# Caixa de aviso de pergunta protegida precisa de tradução

Tags: suporte, tradução

Como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo e [nesta pergunta recente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193738/28595), a caixa de aviso de pergunta protegida parece que voltou a ser em inglês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso necessitem da tradução antiga, deixo aqui linkado a pergunta com a tradução antiga:

[Falta tradução de "Pergunta Protegida"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/852/falta-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-pergunta-protegida/1976#1976)

Answer (score 1):

Coloquei no transifex, só falta o chefe aprovar.