# Alguma traduções

Tags: bug, tradução

Sugeri algumas traduções no Transifex. Estou postando aqui pra catalogar (e talvez eu acabe sugerindo mais algumas e editando aqui).

#### Caixa com o link para compartilhar uma publicação.

Texto original

> share a link to this question (includes your user id)

Sugestão

> compartilhe um link para esta pergunta (inclui o seu id de usuário)

Mais algumas variações - trocando pergunta por resposta e sem os parênteses.

[image: box de compartilhar perguntas e respostas]

---

#### Seção links em ferramentas (de análise)

<sup>O último link</sup>

Texto original

> protected questions

Sugestão

> perguntas protegidas

Mais algumas variações - com a primeira letra maiúscula a "lista de perguntas protegidas".

[image: seção links em ferramentas]

---

#### [Caixa de aviso de pergunta protegida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5898/18246)

Texto original

> This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

Sugestão (peguei a tradução antiga)

> Esta pergunta está protegida para evitar respostas do tipo "obrigado!", "eu também!", ou spam de novos usuários. É necessário que você tenha pelo menos 10 pontos de reputação para respondê-la.

[image: caixa de aviso de pergunta protegida]

---

#### Link de retornar à publicação ao expandir snnipet

Texto original

> Return to post

Sugestão

> Retornar para a publicação

[image: link de retornar para a publicação]

Comment: Parabéns pela iniciativa! =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabei de importar um bando de traduções. Todas dessas estão lá.

Como o @diegofm disse, obrigado pela iniciativa.

Comment: Se eu fizer mais alterações é melhor ir criado posts pra elas? Ou de qualquer forma você vai acabar vendo e "importando" elas?

Comment: @jbueno Não é necessário fazer posts no Meta pra cada alteração. Se você tem confiança na tradução, ou no problema que tá consertando, pode fazer e me avisar que eu importo.

Comment: Ah, bom. Era isso mesmo que eu queria saber, se precisava te avisar e qual a melhor forma de avisar.

Comment: @jbueno Qualquer aviso tá bom. Mas chat seria melhor, pra não poluir o Meta...